# Updating all the way from angular 5 to 9, problem with angular material @7

Tags: angular

I have a project which has been under low maintenance for over a year, and web development goes quite a bit forward in that time. So now I have the task of updating Angular from 5 to 9. I have been successfully able to go up to Angular 7, but when updating the angular/material library to version 7 I get these:

> ng update @angular/material@7

```
              Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires ">=2.3.1 <8.0.0 || >7.0.0-beta <8.0.0" (extended), would install "9.0.1").
              Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires "7.2.16" (extended), would install "9.0.1").
              Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires ">=2.3.1 <8.0.0 || >7.0.0-beta <8.0.0" (extended), would install "9.0.1").*
```

When checking the dependencies of angular/material, I cannot find that it has dependencies to any of those libraries, so why does it even try to update them? And why to version 9.0.1, since that sounds a little bit like Angular 9?

**EDIT**

Now I understand the reason. @angular/material@7 packages have dependencies defined with ^7.3.2 for example. This notation causes it to fetch the latest package which is the version 9.0.1 (or currently 9.0.2). But the other codelyzer and @angular/http versions do not support this new version.

So, how can I update a package in npm so that it takes the noted dependency versions in package.json instead of the newest ones?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on application size if its not to big I would advise to upgrade straight to 9. But to help you with this problem you probably should run:

```
npm i @angular/compiler@9 @angular/platform-browser@9 @angular/core@9
```

from this error it looks like you have some libraries that where updated to version that require version 9 of those above dependencies.

Comment: The problem is, that when trying to update to Anuglar8+, same kind of errors appear and the update fails.